# Why Numpy omits the dimension of an array

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following problem, I have an array that contains 60 arrays, inside them there are 21 arrays, and inside these last ones there are 3 integers, when I do the shape, it says (60,)
How can I make the reshape to be (60,21,3)?

Comment: Hello.  Please share a minimal representation of your code so that it can be evaluated and recommendations can be made.  Thanks.

Comment: I suspect your array has data type `object`.  You'll have to look into how you created such an array.  It will be easier for someone to help you if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: For a start try `np.stack(arr)`.   If it doesn't give an error, the shape may be something like `(60,21)`.  But, as others stress, check the `dtype` as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you are asking, you didn't leave a whole lot of details. However, here are some basic `numpy` functions that seem like they would answer your question.

```
arr = np.random.rand(2,2,1)
print(arr)
#obviously you can use your dimensions of (60,21,3)
#however I am going to print the array
```

output:

```
array([[[0.76494962],
        [0.20654063]],

       [[0.22742839],
        [0.15418584]]])
```

If you want to print the exact shape, in this case of (2,2,1) `print(arr.shape)` gives the output `(2, 2, 1)`. This is a tuple object stored within the numpy array, therefore will not change unless you re-define the array with a new numpy array. If numpy does not output `(60,21,3)` in your case, there is a very good chance you set your code up incorrectly.

If I want to resize my array it is important that you adhere to the size of your array, in my case if I use the function `np.size(arr)` I get `4`. This is because `2*2*1 = 4` so I must reshape it to a size of something that adheres to the same size. for example these are valid calls:

```
arr = arr.reshape(4)
arr = arr.reshape(1,1,4)
arr = arr.reshape(1,1,2,2)
```

And so on. As long as if you multiply the numbers they come out to `np.size(arr)`. In your case you have the shape `(60,21,3)` therefore you must reshape it to have the size `60*21*3 = 3780`.

I also left an example of the `resize` function below. Again, you did not leave much in terms of details on what you wanted, so I am assuming it is one of the functions or explanations I have outlined in this post.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.random.rand(60,21,3)
>>> arr.shape
(60, 21, 3)
>>> arr = arr.reshape(3780)
>>> arr.shape
(3780,)
>>> arr = np.random.rand(60)
>>> arr.shape
(60,)
>>> arr = np.resize(arr, (60,21,3))
>>> arr.shape
(60, 21, 3)
```

Comment: I don't think `reshape` or `resize` will help here.  If the shape is (60,), you can't add elements by simply reshaping.

Comment: `reshape` keeps the same amount of elements but gives the array a different shape. However keeps the same amount of elements and the same values. `resize` has to add extra values in order to give it it's new shape and size.

Comment: I don't think he wants to fill the larger array with 0s.  He wants to see the arrays that are already present.  The key thing that he hasn't told us about is the `dtype`.  Is it numeric, or object?

Comment: Honestly, either one of us could be entirely correct. He has not left enough information for us to really know what he wants. I really only posted some basic functions in relation to what it may be.

Comment: I am very sorry for not being clearer with my problem, I am new to this, however, Sam's solution is what I needed, thank you very much Sam!

Comment: Daniel, If the `resize` works, then you do not have "array that contains 60 arrays, inside them there are 21 arrays" as described in the question.  You may wish that was the case, but that's not what you actually have.

Answer (score 0):

You probably created a array of lists (objects), for example:

```
b = np.array([0], dtype=np.dtype(object))
b[0] = [4,5,6]
b.shape
```

Gives `b` as:
`array([list([4, 5, 6])], dtype=object)`

and the shape will be (1,), not 'seeing' the 2nd dimension represented by the list

Check of this is the case by running `b.dtype`